# Is it possible to implement nextafter w/o obtaining a binary representation?

Tags: c, algorithm, floating-point, libc

Usually `nextafter` is implemented in the following way:

```
double nextafter(double x, double y)
{
    // handle corner cases

    int delta = ((x > 0) == (x < y)) ? 1 : -1;
    unsigned long long mant = __mant(x);  // get mantissa as int
    mant += delta;
    ...
}
```

Here, a binary representation is obtained using `__mant(x)`.

Out of curiosity: is it possible to implement `nextafter` without obtaining a binary representation? For example, using a sequence of arithmetic floating point operations.

Comment: The short answer is "No".

Comment: I suppose you could loop into the difference between two numbers, reducing the delta until equality (`==`) succeeds.  Why would you want to?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've accidentally removed the reason: out of curiosity.

Comment: I'd say yes, it's possible.  But the usual implementation is superior, for what I hope are obvious reasons.

Comment: @RobertHarvey About the loop: is it possible to do it w/o the loop and/or in a constant number of steps? Example: add, div, add, mul, sub and you'll get the (correct) result.

Comment: I doubt it.  The problem is that the space between any two floating point numbers is not uniform; it varies by the magnitude.  So without dealing with the binary representation directly, you have to "guess."

Comment: You can do it in a constant number of steps by virtue of any fixed-size floating-point having limited exponent range.

Comment: @EOF: There's an answer space below to prove your point.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What point? It's trivially true that it can be done in `O(1)` (constant) time, and I'm not claiming to know a tight `Theta(1)` bound.

Comment: A fact that I'm sure you will illustrate in a well-written answer.

Comment: @pmor Hmm, adding "is it possible to do it w/o the loop and/or in a constant number of steps" instead of the more open ended "using a sequence of arithmetic floating point operations." is even more challenging.  Unclear why one wants to narrow the range of possible answers without even determining/demoing  a first unfettered one.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The question itself is open ended. Better if "w/o the loop and/or in a constant number of steps".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below implements `nextafter` in the ascending direction for finite values for IEEE-754 arithmetic with round-to-nearest-ties-to-even. Handling of NaNs, infinities, and the descending direction is obvious.

Without assuming IEEE-754 or round-to-nearest, the floating-point properties are sufficiently well characterized by C 2018 5.2.4.2.2 that we we can implement nextafter (again in the ascending direction) this way:

- If the input is a NaN, return it, and report an error if it is a signaling NaN.
- If the input is −∞, return `-DBL_MAX`.
- If the input is `-DBL_TRUE_MIN`, return zero.
- If the input is zero, return `+DBL_TRUE_MIN`.
- If the input is `+DBL_MAX`, return +∞.
- If the input is +∞, return +∞. (Note this never occurs with a full `nextafter(x, y)` implementation, as it moves the first argument in the direction of the second argument, so we never ascend from +∞ because we never receive a second argument greater than +∞.)
- Otherwise, if it is positive, use `logb` to find the exponent `e`. If `e` is less than `DBL_MIN`, return the input plus `DBL_TRUE_MIN` (the ULP of subnormals and the lowest normals). If `e` is not less than `DBL_MIN`, return the input plus `scalb(1, e + 1 - DBL_MANT_DIG)` (the specific ULP for the input). Rounding method is irrelevant as these additions are exact.
- Otherwise, the input is negative. Use the above except if the input is exactly a power of `FLT_RADIX` (the input equals `scalb(1, e)`), decrement the second argument of `scalb` by one (because this `nextafter` step transitions from a greater exponent to a lower one).

Note that `FLT_RADIX` is correct above; there is no `DBL_RADIX`; all floating-point formats use the same radix.

If you want to consider `logb` and `scalb` as functions that manipulate the floating-point representation, then they could be replaced by ordinary arithmetic. `log` could find a quick approximation that could be quickly refined to the true exponent, and `scalb` can be implemented in a variety of ways, possibly simply a table look-up. If `log` remains objectionable, then trial comparisons would suffice.

The above handles formats with or without subnormals because, if subnormals are supported, it steps into them with the decrement, and, if subnormals are not supported, the minimum normal magnitude is `DBL_TRUE_MIN`, so it is recognized in the above as the point where we step to zero next.

There is one caveat; the C standard allows it to be “indeterminable” whether an implementation supports subnormals or not “if floating-point operations do not consistently interpret subnormal representations as zero, nor as nonzero.” In that case, I do not see that the standard specifies what the standard `nextafter` does, so there is nothing for us to do to match it in our implementation. Supposing that subnormals are sometimes supported, `DBL_TRUE_MIN` must be a subnormal value, and the above will attempt to work as if subnormal support is currently on (e.g., flush-to-zero is off) and, if it is off, you will get whatever you get.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>


/*  Return the next floating-point value after the finite value q.

    This was inspired by Algorithm 3.5 in Siegfried M. Rump, Takeshi Ogita, and
    Shin'ichi Oishi, "Accurate Floating-Point Summation", _Technical Report
    05.12_, Faculty for Information and Communication Sciences, Hamburg
    University of Technology, November 13, 2005.
    
    IEEE-754 and the default rounding mode,
    round-to-nearest-ties-to-even, may be required.
*/
double NextAfter(double q)
{
    /*  Scale is .625 ULP, so multiplying it by any significand in [1, 2)
        yields something in [.625 ULP, 1.25 ULP].
    */
    static const double Scale = 0.625 * DBL_EPSILON;

    /*  Either of the following may be used, according to preference and
        performance characteristics.  In either case, use a fused multiply-add
        (fma) to add to q a number that is in [.625 ULP, 1.25 ULP].  When this
        is rounded to the floating-point format, it must produce the next
        number after q.
    */
#if 0
    // SmallestPositive is the smallest positive floating-point number.
    static const double SmallestPositive = DBL_EPSILON * DBL_MIN;

    if (fabs(q) < 2*DBL_MIN)
        return q + SmallestPositive;

    return fma(fabs(q), Scale, q);
#else
    return fma(fmax(fabs(q), DBL_MIN), Scale, q);
#endif
}


#if defined CompileMain


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define NumberOf(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof *(a))


int main(void)
{
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    static const struct { double in, out; } cases[] =
    {
        {  INFINITY,                 INFINITY                },
        {  0x1.fffffffffffffp1023,   INFINITY                },
        {  0x1.ffffffffffffep1023,   0x1.fffffffffffffp1023  },
        {  0x1.ffffffffffffdp1023,   0x1.ffffffffffffep1023  },
        {  0x1.ffffffffffffcp1023,   0x1.ffffffffffffdp1023  },
        {  0x1.0000000000003p1023,   0x1.0000000000004p1023  },
        {  0x1.0000000000002p1023,   0x1.0000000000003p1023  },
        {  0x1.0000000000001p1023,   0x1.0000000000002p1023  },
        {  0x1.0000000000000p1023,   0x1.0000000000001p1023  },

        {  0x1.fffffffffffffp1022,   0x1.0000000000000p1023  },

        {  0x1.fffffffffffffp1,      0x1.0000000000000p2     },
        {  0x1.ffffffffffffep1,      0x1.fffffffffffffp1     },
        {  0x1.ffffffffffffdp1,      0x1.ffffffffffffep1     },
        {  0x1.ffffffffffffcp1,      0x1.ffffffffffffdp1     },
        {  0x1.0000000000003p1,      0x1.0000000000004p1     },
        {  0x1.0000000000002p1,      0x1.0000000000003p1     },
        {  0x1.0000000000001p1,      0x1.0000000000002p1     },
        {  0x1.0000000000000p1,      0x1.0000000000001p1     },

        {  0x1.fffffffffffffp-1022,  0x1.0000000000000p-1021 },
        {  0x1.ffffffffffffep-1022,  0x1.fffffffffffffp-1022 },
        {  0x1.ffffffffffffdp-1022,  0x1.ffffffffffffep-1022 },
        {  0x1.ffffffffffffcp-1022,  0x1.ffffffffffffdp-1022 },
        {  0x1.0000000000003p-1022,  0x1.0000000000004p-1022 },
        {  0x1.0000000000002p-1022,  0x1.0000000000003p-1022 },
        {  0x1.0000000000001p-1022,  0x1.0000000000002p-1022 },
        {  0x1.0000000000000p-1022,  0x1.0000000000001p-1022 },

        {  0x0.fffffffffffffp-1022,  0x1.0000000000000p-1022 },
        {  0x0.ffffffffffffep-1022,  0x0.fffffffffffffp-1022 },
        {  0x0.ffffffffffffdp-1022,  0x0.ffffffffffffep-1022 },
        {  0x0.ffffffffffffcp-1022,  0x0.ffffffffffffdp-1022 },
        {  0x0.0000000000003p-1022,  0x0.0000000000004p-1022 },
        {  0x0.0000000000002p-1022,  0x0.0000000000003p-1022 },
        {  0x0.0000000000001p-1022,  0x0.0000000000002p-1022 },
        {  0x0.0000000000000p-1022,  0x0.0000000000001p-1022 },

        { -0x1.fffffffffffffp1023,  -0x1.ffffffffffffep1023  },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffep1023,  -0x1.ffffffffffffdp1023  },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffdp1023,  -0x1.ffffffffffffcp1023  },
        { -0x1.0000000000004p1023,  -0x1.0000000000003p1023  },
        { -0x1.0000000000003p1023,  -0x1.0000000000002p1023  },
        { -0x1.0000000000002p1023,  -0x1.0000000000001p1023  },
        { -0x1.0000000000001p1023,  -0x1.0000000000000p1023  },

        { -0x1.0000000000000p1023,  -0x1.fffffffffffffp1022  },

        { -0x1.0000000000000p2,     -0x1.fffffffffffffp1     },
        { -0x1.fffffffffffffp1,     -0x1.ffffffffffffep1     },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffep1,     -0x1.ffffffffffffdp1     },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffdp1,     -0x1.ffffffffffffcp1     },
        { -0x1.0000000000004p1,     -0x1.0000000000003p1     },
        { -0x1.0000000000003p1,     -0x1.0000000000002p1     },
        { -0x1.0000000000002p1,     -0x1.0000000000001p1     },
        { -0x1.0000000000001p1,     -0x1.0000000000000p1     },

        { -0x1.0000000000000p-1021, -0x1.fffffffffffffp-1022 },
        { -0x1.fffffffffffffp-1022, -0x1.ffffffffffffep-1022 },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffep-1022, -0x1.ffffffffffffdp-1022 },
        { -0x1.ffffffffffffdp-1022, -0x1.ffffffffffffcp-1022 },
        { -0x1.0000000000004p-1022, -0x1.0000000000003p-1022 },
        { -0x1.0000000000003p-1022, -0x1.0000000000002p-1022 },
        { -0x1.0000000000002p-1022, -0x1.0000000000001p-1022 },
        { -0x1.0000000000001p-1022, -0x1.0000000000000p-1022 },

        { -0x1.0000000000000p-1022, -0x0.fffffffffffffp-1022 },
        { -0x0.fffffffffffffp-1022, -0x0.ffffffffffffep-1022 },
        { -0x0.ffffffffffffep-1022, -0x0.ffffffffffffdp-1022 },
        { -0x0.ffffffffffffdp-1022, -0x0.ffffffffffffcp-1022 },
        { -0x0.0000000000004p-1022, -0x0.0000000000003p-1022 },
        { -0x0.0000000000003p-1022, -0x0.0000000000002p-1022 },
        { -0x0.0000000000002p-1022, -0x0.0000000000001p-1022 },
        { -0x0.0000000000001p-1022, -0x0.0000000000000p-1022 },
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOf(cases); ++i)
    {
        double in = cases[i].in, expected = cases[i].out;
        double observed = NextAfter(in);
        printf("NextAfter(%a) = %a.\n", in, observed);
        if (! (observed == expected))
        {
            printf("\tError, expected %a.\n", expected);
            status = EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    return status;
}


#endif  // defined CompileMain
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider FP may/may not support sub-normals, infinity, have unique values for most values (e.g. using 2 `float` for `double`), support +/= 0, without an intimae knowledge of the FP encoding, using assumptions like `mant += delta;` is the *next* value leads to portability failures - even when using binary ops.  Using only FP ops would need many assumptions on the FP encoding.

I think a more useful approach would be to post candidate code that uses "a sequence of arithmetic floating point operations" and then ask for 1) what conditions it fails 2) how to improve?

Comment: So you can do it, just not reliably.

Comment: @RobertHarvey With enough assumptions: like IEEE754, etc., yes, A stopped clock is right twice a day.

Answer (score 1):

For my sample ISO-C99 implementation below I used `float` mapped to IEEE-754 `binary32` because I can get better test coverage that way. The assumptions are that IEEE-754 bindings for C are in effect (so C floating-point types are bound to IEEE-754 binary types, subnormals are supported etc), the rounding mode in effect is round-to-nearest-or-even, and exception signaling requirements specified by the ISO-C standard (`FE_INEXACT`, `FE_OVERFLOW`, `FE_UNDERFLOW`) are waived (the masked response is delivered).

The code may be more complex than it needs to be; I simply separated out the various operand classes and handled them one by one. I used the Intel compiler with the strictest floating-point settings to compile. The implementation of `nextafterf()` from the Intel math library is used as a golden reference. I consider it highly unlikely, but obviously not impossible, that my implementation has a bug that matches a bug in Intel's library implementation.

I am demonstrating three variants below, one of which is suitable for platforms without FMA (fused multiply-add), while another avoids floating-point division which may be slow on some platforms. In general, the stepping mechanism differs between normalized operands and subnormal / zero operands. Stepping from a subnormal towards *negative* zero does not readily work with any general scheme. Each of the three variants uses a different approach of dealing with this: by special casing one single case, by reducing slightly the step size for subnormal operands, or by scaling to positive integers followed by back-scaling.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define VARIANT  (1)  // 1, 2, or 3

float my_nextafterf (float a, float b)
{
    const float FP32_MIN_NORMAL    = 0x1.000000p-126f;
    const float FP32_MAX_NORMAL    = 0x1.fffffep+127f;
    const float FP32_EPSILON       = 0x1.0p-23f;
    const float FP32_ONE           = 1.0f;
    const float FP32_HALF          = 0.5f;
    const float FP32_ZERO          = 0.0f;
    const float FP32_NEG_ZERO      = FP32_ZERO * (-FP32_ONE);
    const float FP32_MIN_SUBNORM   = FP32_MIN_NORMAL * FP32_EPSILON;
    const float FP32_SUBNORM_SCALE = FP32_ONE / FP32_MIN_NORMAL;
    const float FP32_INT_SCALE     = FP32_ONE / FP32_EPSILON;
    const float FP32_ONE_M_ULP     = FP32_ONE - FP32_EPSILON * FP32_HALF;
    const float FP32_ONE_P_ULP     = FP32_ONE + FP32_EPSILON;
    const float FP32_INC           = FP32_ONE_P_ULP * FP32_EPSILON * FP32_HALF;
    
    float r;
    if ((!(fabsf(a) <= INFINITY)) || (!(fabsf(b) <= INFINITY))) { // unordered
        r = a + b;
    }
    else if (a == b) { // equal
        r = b;
    }
    else if (fabsf (a) == INFINITY) { // infinity
        r = (a >= FP32_ZERO) ? FP32_MAX_NORMAL : (-FP32_MAX_NORMAL);
    }
#if VARIANT == 1
    else if (fabsf (a) > FP32_MIN_NORMAL) { // normal
        float factor = ((a >= FP32_ZERO) == (a < b)) ? FP32_INC : (-FP32_INC);
        r = fmaf (factor, a, a);
    } else { // zero, subnormal, or smallest normal
        float scal = (a >= FP32_ZERO) ? FP32_INT_SCALE : (-FP32_INT_SCALE);
        float incr = ((a >= FP32_ZERO) == (a < b)) ? FP32_ONE : (-FP32_ONE);
        r = (a * scal * FP32_SUBNORM_SCALE + incr) / scal / FP32_SUBNORM_SCALE;
    }
#elif VARIANT == 2
    else if (fabsf (a) > FP32_MIN_NORMAL) { // normal
        r = ((a < b) == (a >= FP32_ZERO)) ? 
            (a / FP32_ONE_M_ULP) : (a * FP32_ONE_M_ULP);
    } else { // zero, subnormal, or smallest normal
        float incr = (a >= FP32_ZERO) ? FP32_MIN_SUBNORM : (-FP32_MIN_SUBNORM);
        r = ((a < b) == (a >= FP32_ZERO)) ? (a + incr) : 
            ((a == (-FP32_MIN_SUBNORM)) ? FP32_NEG_ZERO : (a - incr));
    }
#elif VARIANT == 3
    else {
        float factor1 = (fabsf (a) > FP32_MIN_NORMAL) ?
            (((a < b) == (a >= FP32_ZERO)) ? FP32_INC : (-FP32_INC)) :
            ((a >= FP32_ZERO) ? FP32_MIN_SUBNORM : (-FP32_MIN_SUBNORM));
        float factor2 = (fabsf (a) > FP32_MIN_NORMAL) ? a :
            (((a < b) == (a >= FP32_ZERO)) ? FP32_ONE_M_ULP : (-FP32_ONE_M_ULP)); 
        r = fmaf (factor1, factor2, a);
    }
#else // VARIANT
#error unknown VARIANT
#endif // VARIANT
    return r;
}

float uint32_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a)
{
    uint32_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

// Fixes via: Greg Rose, KISS: A Bit Too Simple. http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007
static uint32_t kiss_z = 362436069;
static uint32_t kiss_w = 521288629;
static uint32_t kiss_jsr = 123456789;
static uint32_t kiss_jcong = 380116160;
#define znew (kiss_z=36969*(kiss_z&0xffff)+(kiss_z>>16))
#define wnew (kiss_w=18000*(kiss_w&0xffff)+(kiss_w>>16))
#define MWC  ((znew<<16)+wnew)
#define SHR3 (kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr<<13),kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr>>17),kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr<<5))
#define CONG (kiss_jcong=69069*kiss_jcong+13579)
#define KISS ((MWC^CONG)+SHR3)

int main (void)
{
    float a, b, res, ref;
    uint32_t ia, ib, ires, iref;
    const uint32_t FP32_QNAN_BIT = 0x00400000; // x86 and other architectures
    
    printf ("Testing nextafterf() variant %d\n", VARIANT);
    ia = 0x0000000;
    do {
        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
            switch (i) {
            case 0: ib = ia; 
                break;
            case 1: ib = ia - 1;
                break;
            case 2: ib = ia + 1;
                break;
            case 3: ib = 0x00000000;
                break;
            case 4: ib = 0x80000000;
                break;
            case 5: ib = 0x7f800000;
                break;
            case 6: ib = 0xff800000;
                break;
            default: ib = KISS;
                break;
            }
            a = uint32_as_float (ia);
            b = uint32_as_float (ib);

            res = my_nextafterf (a, b);
            ref = nextafterf (a, b);
            ires = float_as_uint32 (res);
            iref = float_as_uint32 (ref);

            if (ires != iref) {
                /* if both 'from' and 'to' are NaN, result may be either NaN, quietened */
                if (!(isnan (a) && isnan (b) && 
                      ((ires == (ia | FP32_QNAN_BIT)) || (ires == (ib | FP32_QNAN_BIT))))) {
                    printf ("error: a=%08x b=%08x  res=%08x  ref=%08x\n", ia, ib, ires, iref);
                }
            }
        }
        ia++;
        if (!(ia & 0xffffff)) printf ("\ria = 0x%08x", ia);
    } while (ia);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```